# list PDF file features command line tool

Tags: pdf, feature-detection

where can I find command line tool which can list some PDF features, similar to mutool.exe, it shows info about fonts, but I need get more info about file i.e. : is this uses transparency or list vector objects,

Comment: You could look at preflight droplets, which can be called from the command line; however, Acrobat Pro is necessery to run those droplets.

Comment: this is what I need. Thanks